# Can multiple CMake extensions be installed for Visual Studio Code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake

Question from someone new to CMake. The VS Code marketplace has two frequently installed CMake extensions:

```
CMake by twxs (with > 350k installs)
CMake Tools by vector-of-bool (with > 365k installs)
```

Both are highly rated. Can you install both side-by-side or should you install one only?

If relevant, these extensions are already installed:

```
C++ (ms-vscode.cpptools)
C++ Intellisense (austin.code-gnu-global)
```

Comment: The only difference with your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58024331/which-cmake-extension-to-use-for-vs-code) is the **title**. Why recreate the question (and delete previous one) instead of just fixing the title?

Comment: @Tsyvarev: Well, the text was edited to remove any request for an opinion on which extension was better. Since it was a completely new question (and the previous question was closed because of asking for an opinion) it was simpler to recreate a new question.

Answer (score 2):

You can install both of these extensions.

"CMake" by twxs installs CMake syntax support for editing `CMakeLists.txt` files.

"CMake Tools" by vector-of-bool installs a side bar that allows you to configure, build, and install the currently open CMake project.

I would recommend that you install both of these tools.

Answer (score 0):

You can install both of them side-by-side. Each one will be tied to its own extension within the VSC command palette so there shouldn't be any overriding problems.